# My pixel 3xl wont charge when I plug it in. I have to plug and unplug it a zillion times. I tried cleaning it

Tags: google-pixel-3-xl

My pixel 3xl wont charge when I plug it in. I have to plug and unplug it a zillion times. I tried cleaning the port, different cables, different chargers. No joy. I can use the wireless charger, but it's slow. Plugging and unplugging it, and waggling does eventually start it charging, but takes ages to find the exact orientation so it charges. Do I need to buy a new phone???

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for like 18 months. It started happening after cycling in the rain a few times. Anyway, I *finally* found the solution last week. Never seen the solution anywhere else. It's so easy in the end. Very easy:

- simply plug the cable in. no wiggling or anything. It probably won't charge yet. I mean, if it does, then you're good. but if it doesn't ...
- go to 'settings'
- go to 'connected devices'
- find usb, and change from 'controlled by other device', to 'controlled by this device'
- if you are lucky, your phone will start charging :)

Comment: I mean, this worked for a bit, until the motherboard broke entirely, from water damage lol :P